# How do I gain access to the hidden weapons vendor in New Haven?

Tags: borderlands

In New Haven, there is sometimes a second weapons vendor across the street from the usual one.  However, it isn't *always* open.  Is there anything I can do to ensure it is available?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, could we get some freehand circles to highlight this "weapons vendor"?

Comment: There is much speculation to when and why it opens. I am not sure if there is a definitive answer to this. Some people say it is Day/Night and some say it is questline related (Which I think is wrong).

Comment: Apparently it's completely random (according to a 5 minute google search) but I have no proof either way.

Comment: @BenBrocka - Better?

Comment: That's better. Borderland's overly subtle arrow system makes it hard to find things of interest sometimes.

Comment: if you do want constant access to it, there's a way to adjust FOV and clip through the wall to see it in third person view

Comment: @yx. I don't think you can *use* it if you do it that way can you?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot once the vendor has been enabled for the first time, you'll be able to access it every time after that using the FoV trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have completed "Hair of the Dog" from Earl.  After that it should be open all the time, [the fact that it isn't appears to be a bug](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=1862226&postcount=208).

I found that when playing a multiplayer game the door was always open.  In single player, teleporting to New Haven from Middle of Nowhere seemed to almost always open the door.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is entirely random. I play Borderlands far too much, and I've never found any pattern to it. It's definitely worth it to check whenever you're in New Haven, as the hidden vendor has a higher than normal chance of having high quality weapons. I tend to find a lot of oranges in it.

Comment: Oranges? Whaddya gonna do, *juice your enemies to death?* Ba-dum-tsch! Thank you, thank you, I'm here all week.

Comment: @Alex I think its the same concept as combustible lemons from Portal 2.  A new era of citrus weapons! ;)

Comment: +25% sting if it gets in an open wound

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a bit of tweaking, you can access the shop through the wall even if its closed as long as you've enabled the vendor by visiting the "Middle of Nowhere" waypoint.

c/p from the video comments:

> to enable 3rd person view in Borderlands here's what You have to do:
>
> 1. Go to: C:\Documents and Settings\Username\documents\My Games\Borderlands\WillowGame\Config
> 2. Open: WillowInput.ini
> 3. Search for [WillowGame.WillowPlayerInput]
> 4. Add the following below other binds:
>      Bindings=(Name="F3",Command="Camera ThirdPerson",Control=False,Shift=False,Alt=False)
>      Bindings=(Name="F4",Command="Camera FirstPerson",Control=False,Shift=False,Alt=False)
> 5. Now If You press F3 You will go to third person view, F4 brings back first person view, You can change the keys to others I simply prefer using this,

Comment: Nice, but do you know if there's any way to access it on say the 360 (where we obviously don't have access to things like editing the game files)

Answer (score 2):

I found if you log out anywhere BUT new haven and log back in, then FT back to new haven, it will be open. Tried it 10 times, worked 10 times. So, don't log out in New Haven or the door will be locked the whole play session. Did this on PC by the way. Not sure if it will work on xbox360 or not.

Happy Vault Hunting!

EDIT - I can also confirm this vendor box will only open up when you get to Middle of Nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, its only open if you are doing the quest line from Marcus & you are visiting New Haven during the daytime.

I also found this:

> This opened once I completed the quest 'IVE GOT A SINKING FEELING' and
>   found the 110101 Eridian Blaster.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually stuck closed if you start off in New Haven that play session. Meaning, if you log out in New Haven to farm the chests when you get back on, checking the hidden vendor along with it doesn't quite go to plan as the door will usually be closed. Porting out of town and back should open it back up. It does only open for the first time after you've reached far enough in the game. I believe reaching Middle of Nowhere unlocks it as others mentioned.